# Getting "Problem parsing the package" after building apk with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, package

Despite a lot of effort's to install the built apk with Unity and trying these step's :

- creating a keystore
- setting package name
- using Api level 16 for minimum API level
- Api compatibility level : .NET Standard 2.0
- Scripting backend : IL2CPP
- Install location : Automatic
- Write permission : Internal

The app gets installed on older device's but new devices that have higher android version throw error's like "problem parsing the package" or "not installed because of invalid package"

Do I have to write an android manifest ? what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing API level to Android 10 fixed it